# Displaying fields from my content types in a module

Tags: 7, nodes, database

I am learning how to write modules at the moment. The following piece of code simply pulls out of the database some data and selects just the nid, title and created fields

```
function photo_gallery_contents($display){

$max_num = variable_get('photo_gallery_max', 3);

$query = db_select('node', 'n')
->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'created'))
->condition('status', 1) //Published.    
->condition('type','portfolio') // Only want our photos aka Portfolio content type
->orderBy('created', 'DESC'); //Most recent first.

if ($display == 'block') {
// Restrict the range if called with 'block' argument
$query->range(0, $max_num);
} // Now proceeds to execute().
// If called by pge, query proceeds directly to execute()

return $query->execute();
```

}

This works fine but how do I access the other fields I created for my "portfolio" content type such as "field_image" or "field_category" both of which I added? I just cannot work out how to do this. Your help will be so appreciated!

I've written other hooks that represent this information on the page or block, at the moment I am showing a list of links to my nodes. I want them to be images with links instead:

```
function _photo_gallery_page() {
$result = photo_gallery_contents('page');
//Array to contain items for the page to render.
$items = array();
//Iterate over the resultset and format as links.
foreach ($result as $node) {
  $items[] = array(
  'data' => l($node->title, 'node/' . $node->nid),
  ); 
}

if (empty($items)) { //No content in the last 2 weeks.
  $page_array['photo_gallery_arguments'] = array(
    //Title serves as page subtitle
    '#title' => t('All photos from ever'),
    '#markup' => t('No photos available.'),
  );
  return $page_array;  
} 

 else {
  $page_array['photo_gallery_arguments'] = array(
    '#title' => t('All photos from ever'),
    '#items' => $items,
    //Theme hook with suggestion.  
    '#theme' => 'item_list__photo_gallery',
  );
  return $page_array;
}
```

}

So how do I swap $node->title to show the image instead?

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to grab just the node ids from the table, and use the [`node_load_multiple()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7) function to load the node objects.

The field data will be attached to those objects, and you can use other API functions to extract the data/build the display HTML ([`field_get_items()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) and [`field_view_field()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7) respectively).

Some sample code that should help:

```
function photo_gallery_contents($display){
  $max_num = variable_get('photo_gallery_max', 3);

  $query = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('nid'))
    ->condition('status', 1) //Published.    
    ->condition('type','portfolio') // Only want our photos aka Portfolio content type
    ->orderBy('created', 'DESC'); //Most recent first.

  if ($display == 'block') {
    // Restrict the range if called with 'block' argument
    $query->range(0, $max_num);
  }

  // Fetch the results for the nid field into an array
  $nids = $query->execute()->fetchCol(); 

  // Load the node objects and return
  return node_load_multiple($nids);
}

function _photo_gallery_page() {
  $result = photo_gallery_contents('page');

  //Array to contain items for the page to render.
  $items = array();
  //Iterate over the resultset and format as links.
  foreach ($result as $node) {
    // Build a render array based on the field's display settings.
    $image = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_image');

    // Render the array down to the image HTML
    $image_html = drupal_render($image);

    $items[] = array(
      'data' => l($image_html, 'node/' . $node->nid, array('html' => TRUE)),
    ); 
  }
}
```